# Roll of different amount along a single axis in a 3D matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a **cube** of shape (x,y,t). I need to shift each (x,y) indices of a varying number of position **along the t axis**. Basically I have something like:

```
roll_matrix = [[0,5,9,0], [3,2,0,0]]
```

The roll_matrix specifies, for each (x,y) position how much to shift along the remaining axis **(axis=2)**. I never need to roll along other axis.

For example, cube[1,0] must shift 3 position, cube [0,0] must stay as-is, etc. I don't care too much what happens with the rolled values - ideally just move them form the front to the end of the array along the time axis. But I could pad with neutral values, in case some slicing notation would do the trick.

I care more about speed than what happens with rolled over values, in other words.

I currently have a for-loop that takes forever. I need an optimized notation to accomplish this instead. I looked up numpy.roll(), however it only allows you to roll along more than one axis, not to perform different roll values along the same one....

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The current for loop:

```
import numpy as np

cube = np.linspace(0,39,40)
cube = cube.reshape((2,2,10))
roll_matrix = np.array([[4,0],[3,2]])
print(cube)
print("")
def roll(cube, roll_matrix):
    cp_cube = np.copy(cube)
    Rawf = cube.reshape(cube.shape[0] * cube.shape[1], cube.shape[2])
    ThPosf = roll_matrix.reshape(roll_matrix.shape[0] * roll_matrix.shape[1])

    RawThf = Rawf
    for i, trigger_value in enumerate(ThPosf):
        RawThf[i, :] = np.roll(Rawf[i, :], -trigger_value)

    RawTh = RawThf.reshape(cube.shape[0], cube.shape[1], cube.shape[2])
    return RawTh

ans = roll(cube, roll_matrix)
print(ans)
```

While yields:

Initial data:

```
[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
  [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]

 [[20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29.]
  [30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39.]]]
```

Rolled data:

```
[[[ 4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.  0.  1.  2.  3.]     #shifted 4
  [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]]    # no shift, 0

 [[23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 20. 21. 22.]     #shifted 3
  [32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39. 30. 31.]]]   # 2
```

`roll_matrix` isn't being used other than here - it's the output from a calculation that tells me how much each to move to be aligned along the time axis. Basically the data obtained is misaligned and I need to align them properly along the time axis.

Comment: can you post some toy data and code?

Comment: Well, I'm looking to get ride of the for loop, but I could post it yeah 1 min.

Comment: What is the expected output of `cube` for the case of `[0,0,3]` i.e., shifting 3 positions?

Comment: This would not be a possible case len(roll_matrix) == x*y

Comment: What you describe would mean roll_matrix = [[3,3],[3,3]], or shifting each position of 3 in the time axis. Which would be equal to roll(cube, 3, axis=2)

Comment: yes. I mean what is the expected output when `trigger_value` is 3. based on your code, in that case `RawTh==cube`

Comment: You have 10 elements in the time axis, therefore anything less than 10 as a value in the roll_matrix would simply bring the nth element to position 0 along the time axis. Trigger_value tells you how many position to move for that specific pixel. So no, it wouldn't mean Rawth == cube

Comment: Reshape to 2D input and use linked dup with negative flattened `roll_matrix`.

Comment: Oh - didn't find that one. I will indeed work I believe. Thanks!